# I don't get this joke. Sentence seems like nonsense to me

Tags: jokes

So, I was at the bar last week,

Behind the bar they have these signs with jokes on them. One of them said "If your drinking to forget, please pay me first"(This isn't the question, I get this joke).

Somebody at the bar, noticing it, said to the bartender: "I don't have a drinking to forget, but if I did, what about it?".

The bartender, looked confused, and then the guy pointed to the sign. The bartender still didn't get it, and he laughed at her.

But I didn't get the joke either. This sentence doesn't make any sense to me. Why is it funny?

Comment: The only thing I see is a spelling error: it should be *you're*. But the sentence doesn't make sense with *your*, so I don't see why it should be funny. Apparently, this person at the bar chose to read *your* as a possessive: whose drinking? Your drinking.

Comment: I'm guessing you have to have thrown back a few for that to be funny...

Comment: @Cerberus-  I think that's it.  "your" as a possessive means that "drinking-to-forget" must become a noun phrase, but then there's no verb.  Replace "drinking-to-forget" with "car" for illustration purposes:  "If your car, please pay me first." The customer's comment is pointing out that this makes no sense:  I don't have a car, but if I did, what about it?  It's a very weak attempt at humor while pointing out the *your vs you're* typo.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question. Although, it has need of a [tag:proofreading]. While that'd be generally forbidden on ELU, this seems to be a valid exception.

Comment: @SrJoven What do you mean it needs proofreading? You mean it should be tagged as such? Or that I worded it inadequately?

Comment: I think it should be tagged as such. I used the tag:code for it and usually it shows a tag image, but it just made a link.

Comment: @SrJoven There's no tag wiki for that, and the questions all seem to be closed. Not sure what it's for. I'll leave it up to those who know the site better to determine if it should be tagged as such though.

Comment: It's because the site doesn't allow for proofreading questions: "I'm writing my dissertation and I was wondering if I should use *Has no point* or *Hasn't any point*" At which point, I feel your question is a bit of an exception, though I assume the tag gives away the punchline, so ... :) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He was pointing out the incorrect use of *your* vs. *you're*. The sign uses the possessive *your*, indicating that they're referring to a "drinking-to-forget" that somebody owns, rather than the contraction *you're* which would be correct, i.e. "If you are drinking to forget...".

Comment: Ah okay, I can see why that's kind of funny. It's a little obscure though.

Comment: @cruncher it's supposed to be a little obscure. it's the kind of "joke" a grammar-obsessed person tells to feel superior, because *they* know it should be `you're`. if the other person doesn't get it, even better.

Comment: It's not superiority, it's basic English and any native English speaker should be embarrassed to get this wrong.